# No highlighting on tabs in review queue

Tags: bug, design, review, tabs

Initially [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/86253) the Revision tab is select and highlighted:

> [image]

Since I clicked the tab (even the current one) highlighting is disappeared:

> [image]

Comment: Seems like another hover-related flaw. On a desktop, the highlight re-appears once you move your mouse away.